# Comparar linhas de matrizes com dimensões diferentes e retornar um único vetor logico

Tags: r, matriz, comparação

Tenho duas matrizes de coordenadas, a matriz A com 83213 linhas e duas colunas (longitude, latitude) e a matriz B com 46886 linhas e duas colunas(longitude, latitude). 
Gostaria de comparar as coordenadas dessas duas matrizes e retornar um vetor lógico de tamanho 83213 do tipo c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, ...), sendo verdadeiro se a coordenada da matriz A está contido na matriz B.

Sei que consigo comparar vetores de tamanhos diferentes usando o comando vetor1%in%vetor2, mas como comparar matrizes e a saída ser apenas um vetor lógico?
É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Corrigido** - Para que o teste seja feito simultâneo numa matriz é necessário a verificação em um segundo passo utilizando a função `ALL()`:

```
a <- matrix(1:50, ncol = 2)
b <- a[seq(1,25, 2), ]

a%in%b # o resultado aparenta estar correto

c <- rep(FALSE, 25)

for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){
  c[i] <- all(a[i,]%in%b)
}

c # resultado correto // TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE ...


## alterando valores de b // todos devem ser falsos
b[,1] <- b[,1] + 1

a%in%b # resultado errado

d <- rep(FALSE, 25)

for(i in 1:dim(a)[1]){
  d[i] <- all(a[i,]%in%b)
}

d # resultado correto // FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE ...
```